# React-select Creatable component not acting in default manner

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

This is my Creatable component:

```
function optionsForSelect(field) {
  return field
    .values
    .map((fieldOption) => {
      return {value: fieldOption, label: fieldOption};
    });
}

function PatientSelectInput({field, options, value, onChange, disabled}) {
  const className = field.id + '-select';
  return (
    <label className={cx('input-label', className)}>
      <div className="label-text">{field.displayName}</div>
      <Creatable
        value={value}
        onChange={(selectedValue) => onChange(selectedValue ? selectedValue.value : null)}
        disabled={disabled}
        onBlurResetsInput={false}
        onCloseResetsInput={false}
        options={options} />
    </label>
  );
}
```

It is a functional component. When it renders, I can create a new option but when I hit tab or enter or click on the automatically generated "Create Option..." the newly created option disappears. I just want the default behavior.

What am I missing?

Comment: I am on react-select version 1.2.1, the latest. Also React 16.2

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this version of react-select mutates it's `options` prop.
This is very bad coding and is fixed in version 2: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2484

The issue you're experiencing is coming from the way you construct the options. Your function creates a new object on each render, replacing the array containing the option you just created.

If you can't update your version I suggest you save the output of `optionsForSelect` to `this.state.options`, then pass the state variable into react-select. The upshot of doing this is you still have the ability to mutate the state of your element and limits the impact of the mutate.